# Allow all html tags except script in TINYMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using TinyMCE for web development, but I have a problem when disable script tag from the content, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Abc</textarea>
  </form>

  <script src="./tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea#mytextarea",
      theme: "modern",
      height: 300,
      plugins: [
          "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
          "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
      ],
      invalid_elements: "script",
      valid_elements: '*[*]',
      toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I googled to find out the solution to this problem but nothing really helpful.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: and.... check on your receiving server. Always check on your receiving server, because it is trivially easy to work around tinymce's restriction.

Answer (score 0):

While `"script"` is technically a valid value for `invalid_elements:`, it will not have a noticeable effect as script tags are already disabled in the TinyMCE Editor.